# How to extract character n-grams based on a large text

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a large text file I want to extract the character n-grams using Apache Spark (do the task in parallel).

Example input (2 line text):
line 1: (Hello World, it)
line 2: (is a nice day)

Output n-grams:
Hel - ell -llo -lo_ - o_W - _Wo - Wor - orl - rld - ld, - d,_ - ,_i - _it - it_ - t_i - _is - ... and so on. So I want the return value to be a RDD[String], each string containing the n-gram.

Notice that the new line is considered a white space in the output n-grams. I put each line in parenthesis to be clear. Also, just to be clear the string or text is not a single entry in a RDD. I read the file using sc.textFile() method.

Comment: Do you need the output 3-grams in order?

Comment: Yes, I do need them in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to take all the lines within each partition and combine them into a long String. Next, we replace " " with "_" and call sliding on this string to create the trigrams for each partition in parallel.

**Note:** The resulting trigrams might not be 100% accurate since we will miss few trigrams from the beginning and the end of a each partition. Given that each partition can be several million characters long, the loss in assurance should be negligible. The main benefit here is that each partition can be executed in parallel.

Here are some toy data. Everything bellow can be executed on any Spark REPL:

```
scala> val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("Hello World, it","is a nice day"))
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[12] 

val trigrams = data.mapPartitions(_.toList.mkString(" ").replace(" ","_").sliding(3))
trigrams: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[14]
```

Here I will collect the trigrams to show how they look like (you might not want to do this if your dataset is massive)

```
scala> val asCollected = trigrams.collect
asCollected: Array[String] = Array(Hel, ell, llo, lo_, o_W, _Wo, Wor, orl, rld, ld,, d,_, ,_i, _it, is_, s_a, _a_, a_n, _ni, nic, ice, ce_, e_d, _da, day)
```

Comment: I think you are right and that is the best way to parallelize this task although not 100% accurate due to the missing n-grams. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like the following:

```
def n_gram(str:String, n:Int) = (str + " ").sliding(n)
```

I am assuming the newline has been stripped off when reading the line, so I've a added a space to compensate for that. If, on the other hand, the newline is preserved, you could define it as:

```
def n_gram(str:String, n:Int) = str.replace('\n', ' ').sliding(n)
```

Using your example:

```
println(n_gram("Hello World, it", 3).map(_.replace(' ', '_')).mkString(" - "))
```

would return:

```
Hel - ell - llo - lo_ - o_W - _Wo - Wor - orl - rld - ld, - d,_ - ,_i - _it - it_
```

Comment: I dont see the use of spark here, so nothing is executed in parallel. I think at least.

Comment: This function just splits a string into n-grams in a thread-safe way. You would use spark to get the strings, call this function, and continue processing them as needed. This function can be called in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need the whole extraction to be executed in parallel if there is a way. I read the file using sc.textFile(), I edited my question and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I have never used spark, but you could probably do something like: `sc.textFile().flatMap(line => n_gram(line, 3))`

Comment: Yes, thats the first thought but I lose the information between lines. For example the line ends with it and the next line starts with is. I cannot connect those two to get the ngrams _it - it_ - t_i - _is - ...

Comment: OK. Then you cannot process the file line by line, and probably cannot process it in parallel in a very straightforward way, as there is no clear split of the file to feed into parallel tasks.

Comment: Does sc.textFile() provide a `sliding` method? If it does, I can help you create a function that does what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, no it does not.

Comment: You have to iterate over the input in order to do this, so it's not going to parallelize well.   To be honest. you might as well pre-process the file outside of Spark to get the n-grams, then make an RDD from the ngrams. Marginally faster might be to preprocess the file, adding the last two characters from the previous line to the start of this one. Load the result into Spark and using sliding(3) on each line to get the n-grams. But really, making the ngrams outside of Spark is going to be pretty quick

Answer (score 0):

There may be shorter ways to do this,

Assuming that the entire string (including the new line) is a single entry in an RDD, returning the following from flatMap should give you the result you want.

```
val strings = text.foldLeft(("", List[String]())) {
  case ((s, l), c) =>
    if (s.length < 2) {
      val ns = s + c
      (ns, l)
    } else if (s.length == 2) {
      val ns = s + c
      (ns, ns :: l)
    } else {
      val ns = s.tail + c
      (ns, ns :: l)
    }
}._2
```

Comment: The entire string is not a single entry in a RDD. I use sc.textFile("myFile").

Comment: That'll be far more difficult to manage.

You can use the code above to get 1 RDD with all the "middle" 3-grams.

Separately, you could attempt to find the 3-grams that cross line borders, but that will involve combining an RDD entry with the next/previous entry and I haven't come across a way to do that.